# Android Custom Explicit Intent

Tags: android

Hi every body I just wanna ask a question, when you define some thing like this in your android manifest file :

```
<activity android:name= "com.example.myapp.ExampleActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name= "some.custom.action" />
    <category android:name= "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and you gonna start it by this way :

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = "some.custom.action"
startActivity(intent)
```

so is it implicit calling activity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an implicit intent.  An explicit intent specifies the exact component that it calls.  Because this doesn't, it's implicit (and therefore might resolve to multiple components if more than one matches).

Comment: Note that for purposes for restrictions that apply to implicit intents, specifying the package name alone is enough to fall under the same bucket as other explicit intents (as in both cases, you know exactly what app will receive the message).